# DNS resolution doesn't work if domain name is included

Tags: domain-name-system, linux-networking, bind, ubuntu-16.04

I have a Ubuntu Server 16.04 acting as DNS and DHCP. Here I have defined the domain name: me.local. I also defined two hosts:

- rpi1.me.local
- rpi2.me.local

Both hosts go to the same server (192.168.1.10) and on this server I have defined 2 virtual hosts:

- rpi1 -> localhost:8080
- rpi2 -> localhost:8090

On a 3rd system, I try the following:

- ping rpi1.me.local -> returns name or service not known
- ping rpi1 -> returns 192.168.1.10
- ping rpi2.me.local -> returns name or service not known
- ping rpi2 -> returns 192.168.1.10

The problem is that I actually need to access http://rpi1.me.local so that the correct site is opened. Using http://rpi1 opens the default Apache2 page.

If I do this on a Windows system, it works as expected! Problem is only on Linux systems (I tried on multiple ones). any ideas what I may be doing wrong? Let me know if you need any other info.

Thanks,
Mircea

Comment: 1) Is your DNS server doing multicast DNS?  2) What about `ping rpi1.me.local.` from the linux box (note canonicalising final dot)?

Comment: I doubt your DNS server is working correctly. The short name is resolved using mDNS or LLMNR, which is done peer-to-peer and does not involve your DNS server at all. By the way, you shouldn't use `.local` as your top level domain, since it is reserved for mDNS (and may be the cause for your troubles).